# Show post if true/false is no ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

How to display only posts, what have field "nezobrazovat" as false?

This is my code:

```
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 3,
            'post_type' => 'mycustompost',
            'key'=> 'nezobrazovat',
            'value'=>'no',
        );
```

This doesnt work, all first 3 posts are displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the acf docs the value is 1 or 0

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'show_in_sidebar',
            'value' => '1',
        )
    )
) );
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/true-false/

Comment: but also 1 or 0 doesnt work

Comment: are you using it as a meta_query? as suggested in docs